# cJSON field does not exist

Tags: cjson

I have a JSON array as follows. I am using cJSON to parse it. However, I want to check if a field exists in my array. I have tried to use cJSON_GetObjectItem and cJSON_IsNull and compare its return value to NULL to determine if a field does not exist.

But, that does not seem to work. Is there some other way to find out if a field is present or not (ex: age is not present in the second subarray)?

```
  "people":
   [
    {
        "name": "Mickey",
        "age": 7
    },

    {
       "name": "Susan"

    }
]
```

Comment: It doesn't work because null is a value. If the field doesn't exist, it's not null. You might want to try `cJSON_IsInvalid`: "Represents an invalid item that doesn't contain any value."

Comment: I have tried cJSON_IsInvalid as well, and compared it to (cJSON_bool)1, but that also didn't seem to work.

Comment: `cJSON_GetObjectItemCasSensitive` should return `NULL` for the key "age".

Answer (score 0):

To check if a key in json exists, can do something like:

```
   cJSON *name=cJSON_GetObjectItem(root,"name");
   cJSON *age=cJSON_GetObjectItem(root,"age");

   if (name) printf("name: %s\n",name->valuestring);   
   if (age) printf("age: %s\n", age->valuestring);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cJSON *age=cJSON_GetObjectItem(root,"age");

if (cJSON_IsString(age) && (age->valuestring != NULL))
{
 printf("The age is %s. \n", age->valuestring);
}
else
{
 printf("The age is  NULL. \n");
}
```